# Error in IP address length when converting from DDN to binary

Tags: php

This is what I use to convert IP addresses from Dotted Decimal Notation to binary:

```
base_convert(bin2hex(inet_pton($ip_address),16,2)
```

This seems to be working fine for **most** IP addresses, but some of them result in a smaller output string (i.e. less than 32 characters). For example, this are two outputs:

```
10.77.55.3
172.30.99.4
```

become

```
1010010011010011011100000011
10101100000111100110001100000100
```

I am expecting all input IP addresses to be 32 characters long after the conversion. How can I make sure that this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's leaving off the leading zeroes. You can add them back in via str_pad.

```
str_pad(base_convert(bin2hex(inet_pton($ip_address),16,2)), 32, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Or to reduce function calls and avoid base_convert() you could do as Michael has suggested:

```
str_pad(decbin(ip2long('10.77.55.3')), 32, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this could be done with `ip2long()` and no need for `base_convert()`, something like `str_pad(decbin(ip2long('10.77.55.3')), 32, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Please consider adding your comment as an answer so that I can at least upvote it ;)

Comment: @user1301428 No need in spreading it across 2 answers - I would recommend Chris edit this answer to include it as an alternative solution..